# libpng 1.6.35 : Unable to render image using image format as RGBA or BGRA

Tags: image, image-processing, png, libpng

I am trying to use `libpng1.6.35` library to decode image data from the given input buffer and return back the decode buffer to the renderer. I want the image with a transparent background.

Below is the image which I am trying to render:

[image: image which I am trying to render]

```
#include "png.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char g_image[0x00080000]; 

unsigned char * PngFileToRGBA(unsigned int *width,
unsigned int *height)
{
     png_image image;
     memset(&image, 0, (sizeof image));
     image.version = PNG_IMAGE_VERSION;
     png_image_begin_read_from_memory(&image,
     png_const_voidp(g_image), sizeof(g_image));  /*g_image contains the 
                                                    input image buffer to 
                                                    decode*/
    png_bytep buffer1;                           /*buffer1 is output 
                                                  decoded image buffer.*/
    image.format = PNG_FORMAT_BGRA;
    buffer1 = (png_bytep)malloc(PNG_IMAGE_SIZE(image));
    if (buffer1 != NULL &&
    png_image_finish_read(&image, NULL/*background*/, buffer1,
        0/*row_stride*/, NULL/*colormap*/) != 0)
   {
        return buffer1;

   }
}
```

If I use image format as BGR, I get the correct output image using buffer1, but with image format as BGRA, the output image is washed out. Please guide what I am missing here.

Output rendered images with BGR and BGR format:

[image: with image format as BGR]

with image format as BGRA:

[image: with image format as BGRA]

It behaves the same even if I use image format as RGB/RGBA.

Comment: You seem to have removed all include files, all setup and image-loading code, and all comments from your code...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Updated the code with the include files. Actually, I get the PNG image in base-64 encoded format, embedded in a SVG file. I decode the base64 encoded image data and pass it to the buffer g_image[] (I have omitted that part as it's code is too long and is not needed here). As far the libpng is concerned, I haven't touched any of its code.